# Dockerising a node project with rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I am trying to dockerise my project where I used RabbitMq. I have written my docker and my docker-compose.yml but I keep getting an error when I run `docker-compose build` How can I get resolve this error.

> [4/4] Building fresh packages... error
>   /home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt: Command failed. Exit code: 1
>   Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build Arguments: 
>   Directory: /home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt Output:
>   node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok node-pre-gyp info using
>   node-pre-gyp@0.13.0 node-pre-gyp info using node@10.16.3 | linux | x64
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
>   node-pre-gyp info check checked for
>   "/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node"
>   (not found) node-pre-gyp http GET
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp http 404
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and
>   node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp)  node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
>   gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
>   gyp info using node@10.16.3 | linux | x64 gyp info ok  gyp info it
>   worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 gyp info using
>   node@10.16.3 | linux | x64 gyp http GET
>   https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-headers.tar.gz
>   gyp http 200
>   https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-headers.tar.gz
>   gyp http GET
>   https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.16.3/SHASUMS256.txt gyp http
>   200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.16.3/SHASUMS256.txt gyp
>   info spawn /usr/bin/python2 gyp info spawn args [
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
>   gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', gyp info spawn args   '-f', gyp
>   info spawn args   'make', gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn
>   args   '/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
>   '/root/.node-gyp/10.16.3/include/node/common.gypi', gyp info spawn
>   args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dvisibility=default', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/10.16.3', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.node-gyp/10.16.3/<(target_arch)/node.lib', gyp
>   info spawn args
>   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt', gyp info
>   spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
>   gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', gyp info spawn args
>   '--generator-output', gyp info spawn args   'build', gyp info spawn
>   args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ] gyp info ok  gyp info it worked if it ends
>   with ok gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 gyp info using node@10.16.3 |
>   linux | x64 gyp info spawn make gyp info spawn args [
>   'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ] make: Entering directory
>   '/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/build'   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o make: g++: Command not
>   found make: *** [bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103:
>   Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127 make: Leaving
>   directory '/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/build' gyp ERR!
>   build error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:248:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.19.76-linuxkit gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib"
>   "--module_path=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
>   "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
>   "--node_napi_label=node-v64" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3 gyp
>   ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok  node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
>   --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/home/message-broker/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:982:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   command "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v
>   v10.16.3 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0 node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   not ok  Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
>   --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/message-broker/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1) info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this
>   command.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine
# FROM node:8.16-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git curl openssh make python \
    busybox-extras yarn

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
# RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs


LABEL maintainer="ugbeadie@gmail.com"
RUN mkdir -p /home/message-broker
WORKDIR /home/message-broker
RUN yarn global add pm2
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn

ENV RABBIT_USER=""
ENV RABBIT_PASSWORD=""
ENV RABBIT_HOST=""
# ENV PORT=5000
ENV NODE_ENV=development
ENV REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
ENV REDIS_PORT=6379

COPY . /home/message-broker
RUN yarn && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc
# COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
# ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
# RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
# RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
# RUN yarn global add typescript

RUN yarn tsc

EXPOSE 5500
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
#COPY . /home/message-broker

#COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
#ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
#RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
#RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
#ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

#RUN yarn tsc

#EXPOSE 5000
#CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
HOST_DOMAIN="host.docker.internal"

yarn tsc

pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js
```

**ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Application configuration section
   * http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
   */
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Message-Broker Server',
      script: './dist/start.js',
      source_map_support: true,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
    },
  ],
};
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.4
    networks:
      - main_network

  message-broker:
    container_name: message-broker
    image: message-broker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - RABBIT_USER=""
      - RABBIT_PASSWORD=""
      - RABBIT_HOST=""
      - PORT=5000
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/message-broker
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - main_network

networks:
  main_network:
    driver: bridge
```

new error when running `docker-compose up`

```
message-broker    | 2020-01-27T15:50:32: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
message-broker    | 2020-01-27T15:50:33: PM2 error: Error: Script not found: /home/message-broker/dist/start.js
message-broker    | 2020-01-27T15:50:33: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
```

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/736#issuecomment-510285927

`RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python`

Comment: That fixed it thanks

Comment: @JuanDM I just updated the question with a new error got after build

Comment: The error is clear, test passing full path to pm2 config file `script: 'home/message-broker/dist/start.js'` if it works you should check your relative path